# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when load the value from Firebasedatabase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I am pretty new with swift. I tried to finger out myself. I know this is the common question, but I hope I could get help. When I run the application. I got the "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

```
    import Foundation
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseDatabase
    import FirebaseStorage
    import FirebaseAuth

    struct TodoItemDatabase {
    var eventID: String!
    var title: String!
    var staff: String!
    var location: String!
    var starts: String!
    var ends: String!
    var rpeat: String!
    var imageName: String!
    var description: String!
    var secondPhoto: String!
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?
    var key: String!
    var isCompleted: Bool

init (eventID: String!, title: String,staff:String, location: String,starts: String, ends: String, rpeat: String, imageName: String, description: String, secondPhoto: String, key: String = "", isCompleted: Bool){
    self.eventID = eventID
    self.title = title
    self.staff = staff
    self.location = location
    self.starts = starts
    self.ends = ends
    self.rpeat = rpeat
    self.imageName = imageName
    self.description = description
    self.secondPhoto = secondPhoto
    self.key = key
    self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    self.isCompleted = isCompleted
}
init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot){

    **//I get the error from here. However, I think the main reason in tableview below** 

    self.eventID = snapshot.value!["eventID"] as! String
    self.title = snapshot.value!["title"] as! String
    self.staff = snapshot.value!["staff"] as! String
    self.location = snapshot.value!["location"] as! String
    self.starts = snapshot.value!["starts"] as! String
    self.ends = snapshot.value!["ends"] as! String
    self.rpeat = snapshot.value!["rpeat"] as! String
    self.imageName = snapshot.value!["imageName"] as! String
    self.description = snapshot.value!["description"] as! String
    self.secondPhoto = snapshot.value!["secondPhoto"] as! String
    self.key = snapshot.key
    self.ref = snapshot.ref
    self.isCompleted = snapshot.value!["isCompleted"] as! Bool
}
func toAnyObject() -> [String: AnyObject] {
    return ["eventid": eventID, "title": title, "staff": staff, "location": location, "starts": starts, "ends": ends, "rpeat": rpeat, "imageName": imageName, "description": description, "secondPhoto": secondPhoto, "isCompleted": isCompleted]
}
```

}

However, When I run the application, and load the tableview. It appears that error.

```
    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseAuth
    import FirebaseDatabase
    import FirebaseStorage

    var toDoList:[TodoItemDatabase] = [TodoItemDatabase]()

    class CurrentEventViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

var databaseRef: FIRDatabaseReference!{
    return FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}

var storageRef: FIRStorageReference!

@IBOutlet var toDoListTable: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return toDoList.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCell
    let todoItem = toDoList[indexPath.row]
    storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL(toDoList[indexPath.row].imageName)
    storageRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in

        if error == nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
                if let data = data {
                    cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }

            })
        } else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }


    }
    cell.myLabel.text = todoItem.title!

    return cell


}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

        let ref = toDoList[indexPath.row]
        ref.ref?.removeValue()
        toDoList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)



        toDoListTable.reloadData()
    }

}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    toDoListTable.reloadData()

}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let postRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").queryOrderedByChild("isCompleted").queryEqualToValue(false)
    postRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        var newPosts = [TodoItemDatabase]()
        for post in snapshot.children{
            **// I think the reason is the line after.** 
            let post = TodoItemDatabase(snapshot: post as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newPosts.insert(post, atIndex: 0)
        }
        toDoList = newPosts
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
            self.toDoListTable.reloadData()
        })
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL(toDoList[indexPath.row].imageName)
    let storageRef1 = FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL(toDoList[indexPath.row].secondPhoto)
    let itemSelected = toDoList[indexPath.row]
    storageRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
        if error == nil
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if let data = data
                {
                    storageRef1.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data1, error) in

                        if error == nil
                        {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                if let data1 = data1
                                {
                                    let detailVC:DetailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController
                                    detailVC.titleEvent = itemSelected.title
                                    detailVC.staffEvent = itemSelected.staff
                                    detailVC.locationEvent = itemSelected.location
                                    detailVC.startEvent = itemSelected.starts
                                    detailVC.endEvent = itemSelected.ends
                                    detailVC.repeatEvent = itemSelected.rpeat
                                    detailVC.imageDetail = UIImage(data: data)!
                                    detailVC.descriptionDetail = itemSelected.description
                                    detailVC.secondPhotoEvent = UIImage(data: data1)!
                                    detailVC.key = itemSelected.key
                                    self.presentViewController(detailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            print(error!.localizedDescription)
                        }

                    }}
            })
        }
        else
        {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You posted way too much code here to be useful. Your issue is that you force unwrap EVERYTHING from the snapshot key-value store. If any of those values does not exist then as! String will crash by definition. You need to conditionally unwrap or nil coalesce those values.

Comment: @Dare. After getting this error, I have deleted all items in the database. Is it the reason?

Comment: Absolutely could be. if snapshot.value!["eventID"] or any other accessor there == nil, then nil as! String will crash. Using ! in Swift essentially means "I swear that this value absolutely cannot possibly be nil no matter what." if it is, then you "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to conditionally unwrap or nil coalesce these values. Force unwrapping the way you are is not safe.

```
self.eventID = snapshot.value!["eventID"] as! String
```

should probably be

```
eventID = snapshot.value?["eventID"] as? String ?? ""
```

Unfortunately, the compiler loves to suggest force-unwrapping when it encounters optional values. This is almost always a terrible suggestion. You need to get into the habit of handling Optionals gracefully when you encounter .None since Optionals are such an integral part of the Swift language.